# javascript checkbox returns the 1st value by default instead of selected value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**php**

```
// iterating through the data and displaying in table format

foreach($data['schoolList'] as $school)
    {
    echo'<tr>';
    echo '<td><input type=checkbox class=check id=check value='.$school['sid'].'></td>';
    echo '<td>'.$school['sid'] .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$school['name'] .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$school['specialization'].'</td>';
    echo'</tr>';
} 
echo '<button onclick="myFunction()">Apply</button>';
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    //to restrict the user to select only 3 checkboxes

    $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
        let x = $("input:checkbox:checked").length >= 3;     
        $("input:checkbox").not(":checked").attr("disabled",x);
    });
    let y=[];               
    function myFunction() {
        y= document.getElementById("check").value;
        console.log(y);  
    }                             
</script>
```

IT only logs the first school id no matter what i select even if i select more than 1 checkboxes! could any one please help me how to log all console values! thank you!

Comment: you can only ever have a single id in a document. You will always get one input with `getElementById`

Comment: Use class as selector instead of id.

Comment: i used selector too still the same

Comment: displays 1 no matter what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById("check")` returns only the first one element with `id="check"`, because the ID is unique identifier.

Use `getElementsByClassName()` instead or use jQuery:

```
<script>
    //to restrict the user to select only 3 checkboxes

    $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
        let x = $("input:checkbox:checked").length >= 3;     
        $("input:checkbox").not(":checked").prop("disabled", x);
    });
    let y = [];               
    function myFunction() {
        $(":checked").each(function () {
            y.push($(this).val());
        });
        console.log(y);  
    }                             
</script>
```

Comment: @mrDincleman it displays all the checkbox values instead of the values that are checked by the user

Comment: is there any way to do it jquery if its easier? or javascript even!

Comment: @faiz I have update my answer and additionally replace attr() with prop() (http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc)